# How to hold marker's render google-maps-api-3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm parsing an xml with have information of a few (maybe) markers. But, before to reach this point I setup  the map with a default LatLng,etc.

The problem is when add the markers, they are render one by one, I mean, it's not about bandwith or response from google maps, I can see when the marker are showing up. But, this could by normal, but what I want is at least hold the render for the user while they are complete generating.

By the way, I don't put any code, because I don't use any special construction, just model json for google maps v3 with even default options in case I have to do more complex code, but by now it's quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

just construct the markers with visible: false, then call setVisible(true) on all of them.